# connectTimeout not working in mqtt node.js

Tags: node.js, mqtt

I am trying to pass a connectTimout for a specific time 10 secs, but connect Timeout still take default 30 secs.

```
mqtt.connect('mqtts://192.168.0.0', {
                    connectTimeout: 10000,
          })
```

Above code should timeout after 10 secs if wrong endpoint is passed, but it is not working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

use client offline to use connectTimeout.

```
client.on("offline",function(){
     client.end();
});
```